# List all files and folders within a SharePoint document library

Tags: python, object-oriented, sharepoint

**Background:**

I have made two classes. The first is `SharePointHandler`, and contains a few functions that I intend on using to automate some actions on SharePoint. A simplified version of this is shown below:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.folders.folder import Folder
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

from path_handler import PathHandler


class SharePointHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, username:str, password:str, company_site:str) -> None:
        
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.company_site = company_site
        self.client_context:ClientContext
        
        self.create_client_context()


    def create_client_context(self) -> None:

        try:

            ctx_authorization = AuthenticationContext(self.company_site)
            ctx_authorization.acquire_token_for_user(self.username, self.password)
            
            self.client_context = ClientContext(self.company_site, ctx_authorization)

            print(f"\nSharePoint authentication successful.")

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"\nSharePoint authentication failed. The following exception has occured:\n{e}\n")
    
        
    def map_folder(self, to_map:PathHandler) -> tuple[list[PathHandler], list[PathHandler]]: 

        file_handler_list, folder_handler_list = [], []

        def enum_folder(parent_folder):

            parent_folder.expand(["Files", "Folders"]).get().execute_query()

            for file in parent_folder.files: # In the event that the directory ends in a file.
                
                file_handler_list.append(PathHandler(to_map.get_scheme_and_root_from_absolute() + file.serverRelativeUrl))

            for folder in parent_folder.folders: # In the event that the directory ends in a folder.

                folder_handler_list.append(PathHandler(to_map.get_scheme_and_root_from_absolute() + folder.serverRelativeUrl))
                
                enum_folder(folder)

        root_folder = self.client_context.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(to_map.get_relative_from_absolute())

        enum_folder(root_folder)

        print(f"\nMapping complete. {len(file_handler_list)} file/s + {len(folder_handler_list)} folder/s found.")

        return file_handler_list, folder_handler_list
```

The first function `create_client_context` creates a ClientContext instance using the user credentials (necessary for accessing the SharePoint site). The second function `map_folder` is used to recursively append all PathHandler instances of all files and folders to their own lists.

The second class is `PathHandler`, which I've made in an attempt to simplify the way that I make alterations to the urls / local paths as I need them, eg: sometimes I'll need a relative url exclusive of scheme and site name. This class is shown below:

```
import os
import urllib.parse
from pathlib import Path


class PathHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, absolute_path:str) -> None:
        self.absolute_path = absolute_path

    
    def get_filename_from_absolute(self) -> str: # COMPLETE ✓

        parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.absolute_path)

        return os.path.basename(parsed_url.path)

    
    def strip_filename(self) -> str: # COMPLETE ✓

        return self.absolute_path[:-len(self.get_filename_from_absolute())]

    
    def get_relative_from_absolute(self) -> str: # COMPLETE ✓

        parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.absolute_path)

        return parsed_url.path

    
    def get_parent_folder_from_absolute(self) -> str: # COMPLETE ✓

        parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.absolute_path)

        return os.path.dirname(parsed_url.path)

    
    def get_scheme_and_root_from_absolute(self) -> str: # COMPLETE ✓ - Not to be used for local paths

        parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.absolute_path)

        return f"{parsed_url.scheme}://{parsed_url.netloc}"
        
    
    def convert_to_absolute_local(self, local_root:str, global_root:str) -> str: # COMPLETE ✓

        temporary_path = local_root + self.absolute_path[len(global_root):]

        return temporary_path.replace("//", os.sep)

    
    def convert_to_absolute_global(self, local_root:str, global_root:str) -> str: # COMPLETE ✓

        return global_root + self.absolute_path[len(local_root):].replace(os.sep, "//")
```

**My question:**

The above scripts tie into quite a large project, and I am trying to simplify this by incorporating OOP. However, I've not worked in an OOP manner before, and am concerned that `PathHandler` exists unnecessarily. Many of my `SharePointHandler` methods can be simplified to return strings, but to remain consistent, I am encouraged to return instances of `PathHandler`.

Is this `PathHandler` class indeed adding unnecessary complexity to my code? Should I simply remove the class and use the functions as typical helper functions and make the necessary adjustments to the method inputs at the start of a function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using type hints you must be using Python 3 (good). So don't inherit from `object`.

Ideally all members of a class are first set in the constructor. So make your `create_client_context` return a `ClientContext` rather than mutating `self`.

Your `print`s should not exist in `create_client_context`. You can keep your `try` if you narrow `Exception` down to the actual exception type from the client context and rethrow using a custom application domain exception; or else don't `try`/`except` at all.

Recursing on `enum_folder` is risky. It's possible to blow the (fairly shallow) Python stack on a folder nesting level that is too deep.

You might want to use the built-in logger support from `map_folder`, but don't print.

You don't use `password` outside of `create_client_context`, so for safety's sake don't store it on `self`.

Move your `urllib.parse.urlparse` to a centralised call that occurs in the constructor of your `PathHandler` and stores the result on `self`, something like

```
    def __init__(self, absolute_path:str) -> None:
        self.absolute_path = absolute_path
        self.parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.absolute_path)
```

Delete your `# COMPLETE ✓`. All code should be considered complete if it doesn't throw. If you want to mark something *incomplete*, then raise a `NotImplementedError` (this is a reasonable way to write out skeletons).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer - so many improvements seems obvious now that they're mentioned. Regarding the mutation of ```self``` in ```create_client_context```, would it be as simple as dropping ```self``` as a parameter and having the method return an instance of ```ClientContext```?

Comment: As for the potential stack issues with ```enum```, your comments are incredibly valid - I've opted for this method because it allows for utility methods to be passed to ```map_folder``` that use the File and Folder instances as input parameters. This just allows for file operations to be done whilst the folder is being mapped, rather than afterwards. I've done a bit of testing, and so far I've not come close to max depth (never say never).

Comment: The only improvement I'm confused about is the second-to-last one that you've mentioned. If you have any free time, could you perhaps demonstrate what you mean? I'd really appreciate the insight.

Comment: Updated for `parsed_url`